# Colombian digital nomad visa and health insurance duration

Tags: visas, insurance, colombia

There is a [new law](https://www.cancilleria.gov.co/sites/default/files/5477%20del%2022%20de%20julio%20de%202022%20%281%29.pdf) governing visas for Colombia in place since last month. A newly available visa is the "[Digital Nomad](https://www.cancilleria.gov.co/newsroom/news/visa-nomadas-digitales-ya-realidad-comenzara-funcionar-ano-colombia)" (Nómada Digital) visa, which can be given for up to 2 years. However, the catch is that the visa is restricted to the duration of the health insurance policy. I have been looking around at all kinds of places, but I can not find any travel insurance that provides a policy for more than a year.

Unless I misinterpret this, it would mean that many visas will be curtailed by the duration of the health insurance, even if people want to apply for longer periods. But surely this is not the intention of the lawmakers? Am I reading this wrong? Or are 2-year health insurance policies readily available and am I not looking at the right places? Any input is appreciated.

Comment: For such long stays, local resident insurances will likely be the only possibility

Comment: Note: you are looking at "travel insurance", but probably such cases enter in other kind of insurances. Look directly "health insurance" with world wide coverage (or maybe without US and other expensive countries).